# How Windows Handle to associate corresponding object type?

Tags: windbg, wdk, windows-kernel

There are two files. One is `LearnHanle.exe` (It is spelled incorrectly, should be `LearnHandle.exe`), and the other is `pop.exe`.

Source code of these files are here:

```c
// LearnHanle.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    STARTUPINFOW startup = { 0 };
    startup.cb = sizeof startup;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    BOOL createProcResult = FALSE;
    if (!CreateProcessW(L"C:\\pop.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startup, &pi))
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Create Process Failed", "Alert", MB_OK);

    char handle[80] = { 0 };
    sprintf_s(handle, "Process Handle: %llu ProcessId: %llu", pi.hProcess, pi.dwProcessId);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, handle, "Process", MB_OK);
    sprintf_s(handle, "Thread Handle: %llu ThreadId: %llu", pi.hThread, pi.dwThreadId);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, handle, "Thread", MB_OK);
    system("pause");
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

```c
// pop.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    MessageBox(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Just sleep
    Sleep(6000000);
}
```

`LearnHanle.exe` just creates `pop.exe` process then suspends itself.

I viewed the details of `LearnHanle.exe` process with `Process Explorer`, and I found the HANDLE, which associates with `pop.exe` process, and then I got the HANDLE address, as shown here:

```
Basic Information
Name: pop.exe(9092)
Type: Process
Description: Contains threads, an address space, and handles.
Address: 0xFFFFE786E04AF080
```

I debugged Windows 11 kernel with WinDbg, and I used `!object` command to view the HANDLE address. The output is here:

```
0: kd> !object 0xffffe786e04af080
Object: ffffe786e04af080  Type: (ffffe786da2cfd20) Process
    ObjectHeader: ffffe786e04af050 (new version)
    HandleCount: 9  PointerCount: 293899
```

The `ObjectHeader` pointer points at the Object Header of `_EPROCESS` of `pop.exe` process:

```
0: kd> dt _OBJECT_HEADER ffffe786e04af050
nt!_OBJECT_HEADER
   +0x000 PointerCount     : 0n293899
   +0x008 HandleCount      : 0n9
   +0x008 NextToFree       : 0x00000000`00000009 Void
   +0x010 Lock             : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x018 TypeIndex        : 0x47 'G'
   +0x019 TraceFlags       : 0 ''
   +0x019 DbgRefTrace      : 0y0
   +0x019 DbgTracePermanent : 0y0
   +0x01a InfoMask         : 0x88 ''
   +0x01b Flags            : 0 ''
   +0x01b NewObject        : 0y0
   +0x01b KernelObject     : 0y0
   +0x01b KernelOnlyAccess : 0y0
   +0x01b ExclusiveObject  : 0y0
   +0x01b PermanentObject  : 0y0
   +0x01b DefaultSecurityQuota : 0y0
   +0x01b SingleHandleEntry : 0y0
   +0x01b DeletedInline    : 0y0
   +0x01c Reserved         : 0
   +0x020 ObjectCreateInfo : 0xffffe786`dca5ccc0 _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION
   +0x020 QuotaBlockCharged : 0xffffe786`dca5ccc0 Void
   +0x028 SecurityDescriptor : 0xffffd705`63f2962f Void
   +0x030 Body             : _QUAD
```

However,

```
0: kd> dq 0xffffe786e04af080
ffffe786`e04af080  00000000`00000003 ffffe786`e04af088
ffffe786`e04af090  ffffe786`e04af088 ffffe786`e04af098
ffffe786`e04af0a0  ffffe786`e04af098 00000000`9e0b9000
ffffe786`e04af0b0  ffffe786`df8ec378 ffffe786`df8ec378
ffffe786`e04af0c0  00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
ffffe786`e04af0d0  00000000`00200001 00000000`0000000f
ffffe786`e04af0e0  00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
ffffe786`e04af0f0  00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
```

I don't know what the address stores, and how `!object` command gets `pop.exe` process' information.

Then I used `!process` command to view the host process `LearnHanle.exe`.

```
0: kd> !process 0 0 LearnHanle.exe
PROCESS ffffe786e04020c0
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 22a8    Peb: 0036b000  ParentCid: 1344
    DirBase: 999c2000  ObjectTable: ffffd70567953400  HandleCount: 121.
    Image: LearnHanle.exe
```

I looked at `LearnHanle.exe` _HANDLE_TABLE.

```
0: kd> dt _HANDLE_TABLE ffffd70567953400
nt!_HANDLE_TABLE
   +0x000 NextHandleNeedingPool : 0x400
   +0x004 ExtraInfoPages   : 0n0
   +0x008 TableCode        : 0xffffd705`6645a000
   +0x010 QuotaProcess     : 0xffffe786`e04020c0 _EPROCESS
   +0x018 HandleTableList  : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffd705`67953bd8 - 0xffffd705`67133918 ]
   +0x028 UniqueProcessId  : 0x22a8
   +0x02c Flags            : 0
   +0x02c StrictFIFO       : 0y0
   +0x02c EnableHandleExceptions : 0y0
   +0x02c Rundown          : 0y0
   +0x02c Duplicated       : 0y0
   +0x02c RaiseUMExceptionOnInvalidHandleClose : 0y0
   +0x030 HandleContentionEvent : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x038 HandleTableLock  : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x040 FreeLists        : [1] _HANDLE_TABLE_FREE_LIST
   +0x040 ActualEntry      : [32]  ""
   +0x060 DebugInfo        : (null)
```

```
0: kd> dt _HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY
nt!_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY
   +0x000 VolatileLowValue : Int8B
   +0x000 LowValue         : Int8B
   +0x000 InfoTable        : Ptr64 _HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
   +0x008 HighValue        : Int8B
   +0x008 NextFreeHandleEntry : Ptr64 _HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY
   +0x008 LeafHandleValue  : _EXHANDLE
   +0x000 RefCountField    : Int8B
   +0x000 Unlocked         : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x000 RefCnt           : Pos 1, 16 Bits
   +0x000 Attributes       : Pos 17, 3 Bits
   +0x000 ObjectPointerBits : Pos 20, 44 Bits
   +0x008 GrantedAccessBits : Pos 0, 25 Bits
   +0x008 NoRightsUpgrade  : Pos 25, 1 Bit
   +0x008 Spare1           : Pos 26, 6 Bits
   +0x00c Spare2           : Uint4B
```

I want to know how handle table entry in handle table of process to associates with corresponding object type.

And I would also like to know the purpose of these two members: `struct _HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY::ObjectPointerBits`, `struct _OBJECT_HEADER::TypeIndex` and `struct _KPROCESS::Header`(_DISPATCHER_HEADER).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example I'm going to take a file handle (0x1c8) from the explorer process (6496):

[image]

```
1: kd> !handle 0x1c8 3 0n6496

PROCESS ffffe4856647a080
    SessionId: 2  Cid: 1960    Peb: 00238000  ParentCid: 1904
    DirBase: 1409e3002  ObjectTable: ffffd10029c47740  HandleCount: 2981.
    Image: explorer.exe

Handle table at ffffd10029c47740 with 2981 entries in use

01c8: Object: ffffe48565dd7110  GrantedAccess: 00100001 (Inherit) (Audit) Entry: ffffd10029ff9720
Object: ffffe48565dd7110  Type: (ffffe485608f7220) File
    ObjectHeader: ffffe48565dd70e0 (new version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 32783
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \Windows\en-US\explorer.exe.mui {HarddiskVolume3}
```

Start with the handle table from the `_EPROCESS`:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_eprocess ffffe4856647a080 -y ObjectTable
nt!_EPROCESS
   +0x570 ObjectTable : 0xffffd100`29c47740 _HANDLE_TABLE


0: kd> dt nt!_handle_table 0xffffd100`29c47740
nt!_HANDLE_TABLE
   +0x000 NextHandleNeedingPool : 0x3800
   +0x004 ExtraInfoPages   : 0n0
   +0x008 TableCode        : 0xffffd100`29ef4001
   +0x010 QuotaProcess     : 0xffffe485`6647a080 _EPROCESS
   +0x018 HandleTableList  : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffd100`29c47418 - 0xffffd100`29c47d98 ]
   +0x028 UniqueProcessId  : 0x1960
   +0x02c Flags            : 0
   +0x02c StrictFIFO       : 0y0
   +0x02c EnableHandleExceptions : 0y0
   +0x02c Rundown          : 0y0
   +0x02c Duplicated       : 0y0
   +0x02c RaiseUMExceptionOnInvalidHandleClose : 0y0
   +0x030 HandleContentionEvent : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x038 HandleTableLock  : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x040 FreeLists        : [1] _HANDLE_TABLE_FREE_LIST
   +0x040 ActualEntry      : [32]  ""
   +0x060 DebugInfo        : (null)
```

The `TableCode` field points to an array of tables, the lower bits determining which table should be used:

```
0: kd> dq 0xffffd100`29ef4000
ffffd100`29ef4000  ffffd100`29ff9000 ffffd100`29ef5000
ffffd100`29ef4010  ffffd100`255fd000 ffffd100`29d96000
ffffd100`29ef4020  ffffd100`2a1fd000 ffffd100`2a0f7000
ffffd100`29ef4030  ffffd100`258bc000 ffffd100`25b5a000
ffffd100`29ef4040  ffffd100`25bff000 ffffd100`25cfc000
ffffd100`29ef4050  ffffd100`25b57000 ffffd100`25dfe000
ffffd100`29ef4060  ffffd100`258c6000 ffffd100`2802c000
ffffd100`29ef4070  00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
```

The code from the `nt!ExpLookupHandleTableEntry` helps to determine how to use the table array (first param is a `_HANDLE_TABLE*` in RCX, and second param is the handle, in RDX):

```
PAGE:00000001407427E0 ExpLookupHandleTableEntry proc near     ; CODE XREF: ObDuplicateObject+180↑p
PAGE:00000001407427E0                                         ; ExMapHandleToPointer+11↑p ...
PAGE:00000001407427E0
PAGE:00000001407427E0 ; FUNCTION CHUNK AT PAGE:0000000140895396 SIZE 00000022 BYTES
PAGE:00000001407427E0
PAGE:00000001407427E0                 mov     eax, [rcx+_HANDLE_TABLE.NextHandleNeedingPool]
PAGE:00000001407427E2                 and     rdx, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCh
PAGE:00000001407427E6                 cmp     rdx, rax
PAGE:00000001407427E9                 jnb     short loc_140742820
PAGE:00000001407427EB                 mov     r8, [rcx+_HANDLE_TABLE.TableCode]
PAGE:00000001407427EF                 mov     eax, r8d
PAGE:00000001407427F2                 and     eax, 3
PAGE:00000001407427F5                 cmp     eax, 1
PAGE:00000001407427F8                 jnz     short loc_140742812
PAGE:00000001407427FA                 mov     rax, rdx
PAGE:00000001407427FD                 shr     rax, 0Ah
PAGE:0000000140742801                 mov     rax, [r8+rax*8-1]
PAGE:0000000140742806
PAGE:0000000140742806 loc_140742806:                          ; CODE XREF: ExpLookupHandleTableEntry+152BD3↓j
PAGE:0000000140742806                 and     edx, 3FFh
PAGE:000000014074280C                 lea     rax, [rax+rdx*4]
PAGE:0000000140742810                 retn
PAGE:0000000140742810 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAGE:0000000140742811                 align 2
PAGE:0000000140742812
PAGE:0000000140742812 loc_140742812:                          ; CODE XREF: ExpLookupHandleTableEntry+18↑j
PAGE:0000000140742812                 test    eax, eax
PAGE:0000000140742814                 jnz     loc_140895396
PAGE:000000014074281A                 lea     rax, [r8+rdx*4]
PAGE:000000014074281E                 retn
PAGE:000000014074281E ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAGE:000000014074281F                 align 20h
PAGE:0000000140742820
PAGE:0000000140742820 loc_140742820:                          ; CODE XREF: ExpLookupHandleTableEntry+9↑j
PAGE:0000000140742820                 xor     eax, eax
PAGE:0000000140742822                 retn
PAGE:0000000140742822 ExpLookupHandleTableEntry endp
```

In my case it's just the first table in the array, so the handle entry is at `table_base + (handle * 4)`. Even though each table entry is a `_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY` (sizeof 0x10), each handle is a multiple of 4 (so 0x10 / 4 = 4):

```
1: kd> ? ffffd100`29ff9000 + (0x1c8 * 4)
Evaluate expression: -51676341889248 = ffffd100`29ff9720
```

The table entry:

```
1: kd> dt _handle_table_entry ffffd100`29ff9720
nt!_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY
   +0x000 VolatileLowValue : 0n-1980064459403493377
   +0x000 LowValue         : 0n-1980064459403493377
   +0x000 InfoTable        : 0xe48565dd`70e0ffff _HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
   +0x008 HighValue        : 0n1048577
   +0x008 NextFreeHandleEntry : 0x00000000`00100001 _HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY
   +0x008 LeafHandleValue  : _EXHANDLE
   +0x000 RefCountField    : 0n-1980064459403493377
   +0x000 Unlocked         : 0y1
   +0x000 RefCnt           : 0y0111111111111111 (0x7fff)
   +0x000 Attributes       : 0y000
   +0x000 ObjectPointerBits : 0y11100100100001010110010111011101011100001110 (0xe48565dd70e)
   +0x008 GrantedAccessBits : 0y0000100000000000000000001 (0x100001)
   +0x008 NoRightsUpgrade  : 0y0
   +0x008 Spare1           : 0y000000 (0)
   +0x00c Spare2           : 0
```

At least two interesting stuff here:

- `GrantedAccessBits`: which is the granted access mask for the object (here we have `0x100001`, which for a file object it's just `SYNCHRONIZE (0x10000) | FILE_READ_DATA (0x1)`
- `ObjectPointerBits`: which after a calculation will be a pointer to the `_OBJECT_HEADER` of the object.

From the `ObjectPointerBits` value you'll need to do the following to get the object header address: `(ObjectPointerBits << 4) | 0xffff000000000000`

```
1: kd> ? (0xe48565dd70e << 4) | 0xffff000000000000
Evaluate expression: -30213385916192 = ffffe485`65dd70e0

1: kd> dt _object_header ffffe485`65dd70e0
nt!_OBJECT_HEADER
   +0x000 PointerCount     : 0n32783
   +0x008 HandleCount      : 0n1
   +0x008 NextToFree       : 0x00000000`00000001 Void
   +0x010 Lock             : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x018 TypeIndex        : 0x14 ''
   +0x019 TraceFlags       : 0 ''
   +0x019 DbgRefTrace      : 0y0
   +0x019 DbgTracePermanent : 0y0
   +0x01a InfoMask         : 0x4c 'L'
   +0x01b Flags            : 0 ''
   +0x01b NewObject        : 0y0
   +0x01b KernelObject     : 0y0
   +0x01b KernelOnlyAccess : 0y0
   +0x01b ExclusiveObject  : 0y0
   +0x01b PermanentObject  : 0y0
   +0x01b DefaultSecurityQuota : 0y0
   +0x01b SingleHandleEntry : 0y0
   +0x01b DeletedInline    : 0y0
   +0x01c Reserved         : 0
   +0x020 ObjectCreateInfo : 0xffffe485`62c5ecc0 _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION
   +0x020 QuotaBlockCharged : 0xffffe485`62c5ecc0 Void
   +0x028 SecurityDescriptor : (null) 
   +0x030 Body             : _QUAD
```

From the object header you can get the object type by doing the following calculation:

- `*((BYTE*)nt!ObHeaderCookie) ^ second_byte_of_object_header_address ^ _OBJECT_HEADER.TypeIndex`

```
1: kd> db nt!ObHeaderCookie L1
fffff800`7911ed74  4c      

1: kd> ? (ffffe485`65dd70e0 >> 8) & 0xff
Evaluate expression: 112 = 00000000`00000070

1: kd> dt _object_header ffffe485`65dd70e0 -y TypeIndex
nt!_OBJECT_HEADER
   +0x018 TypeIndex : 0x14 ''

1: kd> ? 0x4c ^ 0x70 ^ 0x14
Evaluate expression: 40 = 00000000`00000028
```

The above result (0x28 in this case) is an index into the kernel types array, which is a global variable named `nt!ObTypeIndexTable` (an array of `_OBJECT_TYPE`):

```
1: kd> dt _OBJECT_TYPE poi(nt!ObTypeIndexTable + (0x28 * 8))
nt!_OBJECT_TYPE
   +0x000 TypeList         : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffe485`608f7220 - 0xffffe485`608f7220 ]
   +0x010 Name             : _UNICODE_STRING "File"
   +0x020 DefaultObject    : 0x00000000`0000009b Void
   +0x028 Index            : 0x28 '('
   +0x02c TotalNumberOfObjects : 0x27cc
   +0x030 TotalNumberOfHandles : 0xaae
   +0x034 HighWaterNumberOfObjects : 0x2a42
   +0x038 HighWaterNumberOfHandles : 0xd36
   +0x040 TypeInfo         : _OBJECT_TYPE_INITIALIZER
   +0x0b8 TypeLock         : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x0c0 Key              : 0x656c6946
   +0x0c8 CallbackList     : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffe485`608f72e8 - 0xffffe485`608f72e8 ]
```

So it's a file object ( represented by a `nt!FILE_OBJECT`).

> _DISPATCHER_HEADER

If an object is waitable (i.e. its handle can be passed to `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMutipleObjects`) then it has a `_DISPATCH_HEADER`.